# React hooks - Shopping cart - Proper use of props and prototype?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, object, use-state

I'm trying to build an example shopping cart and came across this example that doesn't seem to work here, but does show each product, price, add to cart button, and correctly tallies up the total when you add to the cart.

**QUESTIONS**

1) Will the use of `concat` cause any prototypal issues that I should worry about?

2) What is the point of doing this part of the code? Why are they setting `props` and `children`? Can this be omitted or refactored without this?

```
const Product = props => {
      const { product, children } = props;
      return (
        <div className="products">
          {product.name} ${product.price}
          {children}
        </div>
      );
    };
```

**CODE**

```js
const Product = props => {
  const { product, children } = props;
  return (
    <div className="products">
      {product.name} ${product.price}
      {children}
    </div>
  );
};

function App() {
  const [products] = useState([
    { name: "Superman Poster", price: 10 },
    { name: "Spider Poster", price: 20 },
    { name: "Bat Poster", price: 30 }
  ]);

  const [cart, setCart] = useState([]);

  const addToCart = index => {
    setCart(cart.concat(products[index]));
  };

  const calculatePrice = () => {
    return cart.reduce((price, product) => price + product.price, 0);
  };

  return (
    <div className="App">
      <h2>Shopping cart example using React Hooks</h2>
      <hr />
      {products.map((product, index) => (
        <Product key={index} product={product}>
          <button onClick={() => addToCart(index)}>Add to cart</button>
        </Product>
      ))}
      YOUR CART TOTAL: ${calculatePrice()}
      {cart.map((product, index) => (
        <Product key={index} product={product}>
          {" "}
        </Product>
      ))}
    </div>
  );
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/react/16.6.3/umd/react.production.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/react-dom/16.6.3/umd/react-dom.production.min.js"></script>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> Will the use of concat cause any prototypal issues that I should worry about?

No, an [Array.concat()](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/concat) would simply return you a new Array reference, which is also correct while setting a state. And why would there be any prototypal issue? You aren't changing anything over the prototype.

> What is the point of doing this part of the code? Why are they setting props and children?

```
const { product, children } = props;
```

You need product and children to display in your product page, you simply extract it from `props`, This way of extracting variables is called [Destructering](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Destructuring_assignment), it the same as:

```
const product = props.product;
const children= props.children;
```

Comment: appreciate the info, im reading somewhere that `push` is quicker than `concat`, if we're going to be adding more and more products would it be better to use `push(...product[id])`? or can stick with `concat`?

Comment: And you're saying that using props is the only way to be able to display on the product page?

Comment: @mph85 I wouldn't comment on the speed, *(which it seems would be more for `push` because it is adding the data in an existing memory location but a concat would create a new one)* but `concat()` seems to be an apt option for you rather than using `push` because every time you change your state, you should to assing a new reference and `concat()` gives you a new Reference

Comment: @mph85 You have `Products` component embedded in your App component and you are setting the attributes `<Product key={index} product={product}>  //`, if you want to access these passed attributes in Products components, you ask the `props`.

Comment: besides readability, would there be any benefit to using a spread operator here instead?